# Может ли таблица иметь несколько внешних ключей на одну и ту же таблицу?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Я проектирую базу данных, которая представляет из себя базу знаний оболочки экспертных систем. И возникла такая ситуация.
[image]

Может ли такое вообще быть? Логическая операция должна связывать две операции сравнения, как это обычно бывает. И правильно ли я указал связь "1:1". Пример: T <= 10 AND T > 0. Слева от логического оператора AND левый операнд, справа - правый.

Comment: *Может ли таблица иметь несколько внешних ключей на одну и ту же таблицу?* Да запросто! Синтаксически никаких ограничений такой для схемы нет. А логически - ссылки должны быть (как правило) на разные записи.

Comment: Мне лично непонятно, как тут связан вопрос с постановкой задачи.

Comment: @Akina да, на разные записи. Спасибо!

Comment: @CrazyElf я привел пример того что мне нужно сделать, и для этого мне нужно связать таблицу с другой посредством двух внешних ключей. Но я задался вопросом, можно ли вообще так делать